# How do I make R use HTML help on Debian?

Tags: r, debian

I am use R 2.14.0 on Debian Squeeze. I am running R in the terminal. Currently when I type 
 `?myfunction` , the help page is displayed in the terminal. I would like for the help page to be displayed in my web browser instead, just like on Windows (or Fedora). How do I do this?
I have tried typing `help.start()` but it did not do anything.

UPDATE: I got it working once, then it stopped working. I added the following lines to `$R_HOME/etc/.Rprofile`

```
options("help_type"="html")

options("browser"="chromium-browser")
```

It worked once. Then stopped.

`help.start()` now launches the browser. However, `?someFunction` only launched the browser once and has now reverted to the in-terminal help.

Thanks.

Comment: Make sure you have the packages `r-base-html` and `r-doc-html` installed.

Comment: Dirk, they are installed. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a single query, use the `help_type` argument to `help()`, like this:

```
help(myfunction, help_type="html")
```

To set the help type for the current R session, set,

```
options(help_type="html")
```

Finally, to change the default help type for all R sessions, add the following line to your `.Rprofile.site` file, located in `$R_HOME/etc/.Rprofile.site` (or to one of the other `.Rprofile` files described in `?Startup`):

```
options("help_type"="html")
```

Comment: Thanks. I implemented the third option. Now I have the problem that although R says `starting HTTP server...` the help entry is not displayed in the browser.

Comment: Do i need to install/enable some other html server?

Comment: You might want to look at setting `options("browser")`. See `?options` for some information about that. I'm mostly a Windows user, so one of the many UNIX users who stop in may be better able to help, particularly if you update/edit your question.

Comment: @power: R has its own internal http server which it uses for help purposes. You don't need to install anything, so don't go downloading Apache!

Comment: Josh O'Brien, thanks. It worked once, then stopped. I have updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @power -- If it worked once, you must be close to a fix. When it didn't work, did you check your options (with `options("help_type", "browser")` to see that those were still set properly?

Comment: @power -- If you continue to have problems, and don't get help with this post, you may want to consider: (a) accepting this one (or not); (b) posting a new question with your carefully documented difficulty (hopefully after figuring out how to recreate the steps and the problems).  This post is unlikely to get much more attention, since it's reasonably old, and has changed quite a bit since most of the 'regular' have seen it.  Best of luck, and let us know if you figure out the problem!

Comment: @power, did you do the last step that Josh suggested? That it worked once, and than failed suggests that you changed the option once and thought it was permanent from then on. However, as Josh said in his answer, you need to add the command to your .Rprofile .

Comment: @Josh O'Brien, Can there be other ".Rprofile"'s that exist in other directories. For example a .Rprofile for each user?

Comment: @power -- Yes, there can be.  In fact (contra the advice I gave you earlier), the file in `$R_HOME/etc/` should be named `.Rprofile.site`, and not `.Rprofile`. (I've now changed it in the post above).  In addition, you can have files that _are_ named `.Rprofile`, which will supplement/override `.Rprofile.site`. They need to be located in either your current directory (from which you launch R), or in your home directory. See `?Startup` for the gory details. (Also, do let me know if you find a fix -- perhaps as simple as renaming `.Rprofile` to `.Rprofile.site`.)  Good luck.

Comment: I got it working!! :-) Thanks Josh. Lessons learnt:
1. The file to modify is `$R_HOME/etc/Rprofile.site`

Comment: 2. R also looks for `.Rprofile` in the `~` (home) directory and in the directory from which R is launched. That is why it worked once for me because I launched R from `$R_HOME/etc/` where `.Rprofile` file was.

Comment: I also added `options(browser="chromium-browser")`

Comment: @power -- Mystery solved!  I had puzzled over why it worked for you once, but never again.  Thanks for updating with the eventual solution.

Comment: Small FYI because I always keep checking back here: On Ubuntu, the default $R_HOME is `/usr/lib/R` so `/usr/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site`